# Select Today's date using BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using Google Cloud SDK (command-line) via C# and I want to select the information for the Current Date(today).

The select is working but I'm not able to bring the latest date on the column DATE
Below is the query I'm using:

```
        var table = client.GetTable("projectId", "datasetId", "table");

        var sql = $"" +
            $"SELECT " +
            $"sku, " +
            $"FROM {table} " +
            $"WHERE DATE=CurrentDate('America/Sao_Paulo') " +
            $"LIMIT 10";
```

Schema: SKU  - String
DATE - Timestamp

Comment: Here is the documentation for the built-in function , [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#current_datetime). The corret function is **CURRENT_DATE()** as @JozefCechovsky mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use CURRENT_DATE instead of CurrentDate

```
var table = client.GetTable("projectId", "datasetId", "table");

var sql = $"" +
    $"SELECT " +
    $"sku, " +
    $"FROM {table} " +
    $"WHERE DATE=CURRENT_DATE('America/Sao_Paulo') " +
    $"LIMIT 10";
```